# samdump2 Error reading ControlSet: _RegOpenKey

Tags: linux, password-cracking

I copied both SAM and SYSTEM files from my Windows7 OS, and then used this command to read the content of the SAM file `samdump2 SAM SYSTEM > mdp_chiffres.txt`, but i'm getting this error `Error reading ControlSet: _RegOpenKey`.

PS : I have a dual boot of Ubuntu 15.10 (Linux) and Windows 7, and this operation i mentioned above is being operated from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i got it to work by following theses steps :

1. You have first to install a compatible version of `samdupm2` and `bkhive` (because I have tested the ones on the repositories and it doesn't work well) using this commands :

   ```
   curl http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/samdump2/samdump2_1.1.1-1.1_i386.deb > samdump2_1.1.1-1.1_i386.deb

   dpkg -i samdump2_1.1.1-1.1_i386.deb

   curl http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/b/bkhive/bkhive_1.1.1-1_i386.deb > bkhive_1.1.1-1_i386.deb

   dpkg -i bkhive_1.1.1-1_i386.deb
   ```

   Ps : If you have problems with dependecies then execute this command `sudo apt-get install -f`
2. Then you have to use `bkhive` on the SYSTEM file with this command `bkhive SYSTEM keys.txt`.
3. And finally we use the `samdump2` to get the hashed passwords using this command `samdump2 SAM keys.txt > hashed_passwords.txt`.

I have just tested it and it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
samdump2 SAM SYSTEM
```

Try:

```
samdump2 SYSTEM SAM
```

The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/samdump2) lists it the same way.
(Just tested this on samdump2 version 3)

Comment: And did you also test it the other way?

Comment: Yes, that is the reason I even left the comment. I was getting the same error as OP then I switched the terms. It kind of makes sense to have SYSTEM first when you think about it because the tool retrieves the syskey then extracts the hashes from the SAM file.

Comment: Then instead of saying "try", then you actually need to be more explicit and say that there is a syntax error. I also see in the man page link I provided that the proper syntax is provided. Right now, your answer is just a one-line command without any relevance or explanation. Add in the explanation and this is a definitive answer.